# Apache httpd directory location precedence

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

Apache 2.2 with ssl on windows 7

I have the following proxy pass config which works great

```
<Location /myproject>
    RequestHeader add X-LocalHeader "Headers For the Win"
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8084/myproject
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8084/myproject
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /myproject http://localhost:8084/myproject
</Location>
```

Now, I want to add another config by which I want that every time the path begins with /myproject/newux to go to a local folder.

I tried this both in front and after the above Location directive but it does not work (the proxy config kicks in first)

```
Alias "/myproject/newux" "D:/apps/Apache2.2/htdocs/myproject/newux"

<Directory "D:/apps/Apache2.2/htdocs/myproject/newux">
    Options Indexes
</Directory>
```

What's the right config?